# Reshaping data column into rows using the package of tidyr and/or reshape in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, reshape, tidyr

I would like to move the last column (in current dataset) into rows (in desired dataset) with the missing data. I have looked through the packages of reshape, reshape2, and tidyr. The function gather() in tidyr package should be the solution but I could not handle it so far. Any suggestions for this ?
Thanks in advance.

***Current dataset:***

```
  date       citycode cityname       cases deaths cases_03_04
1 01-04-2020        1 city1            197      3         241
2 01-04-2020        2 city2             26      0          32
```

***Desired dataset:***

```
  date       citycode cityname       cases deaths
1 01-04-2020        1 city1            197      3         
2 01-04-2020        2 city2             26      0          
3 03-04-2020        1 city1            241     na
4 03-04-2020        2 city2             32     na
```

Comment: You essentially want to `rbind`. However, how does the date come in?

Comment: @NelsonGon Not at all. The last column of currDataSet is distributed into rows in desDataSet from cases_03_04 into cases.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('date citycode cityname cases deaths cases_03_04
01-04-2020 1 city1 197 3 241
01-04-2020  2 city2 26 0 32')


wdt <- dcast(dt,...~date,value.var = "cases")

wdt
#>    citycode cityname deaths cases_03_04 01-04-2020
#> 1:        1    city1      3         241        197
#> 2:        2    city2      0          32         26
setnames(wdt,old = "cases_03_04",new = "03-04-2020")

ldt <- melt(wdt,measure.vars = patterns("2020$"),variable.name = "date",value.name = "cases")

ldt[date=="03-04-2020",deaths:=NA][]
#>    citycode cityname deaths       date cases
#> 1:        1    city1     NA 03-04-2020   241
#> 2:        2    city2     NA 03-04-2020    32
#> 3:        1    city1      3 01-04-2020   197
#> 4:        2    city2      0 01-04-2020    26
```

`tidyr` solution

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('date citycode cityname cases deaths cases_03_04
01-04-2020 1 city1 197 3 241
01-04-2020  2 city2 26 0 32')

df <- tibble(dt)

wdf <- pivot_wider(df,names_from = date,values_from =  cases)

names(wdf) <- c("citycode", "cityname", "deaths", "03-04-2020", "01-04-2020")

wdf
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   citycode cityname deaths `03-04-2020` `01-04-2020`
#>      <int> <chr>     <int>        <int>        <int>
#> 1        1 city1         3          241          197
#> 2        2 city2         0           32           26

ldf <- pivot_longer(wdf,cols =c("03-04-2020", "01-04-2020"),names_to = "date",values_to = "cases")

ldf %>% 
  mutate(deaths=ifelse(date=="03-04-2020",NA,deaths))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   citycode cityname deaths date       cases
#>      <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>      <int>
#> 1        1 city1        NA 03-04-2020   241
#> 2        1 city1         3 01-04-2020   197
#> 3        2 city2        NA 03-04-2020    32
#> 4        2 city2         0 01-04-2020    26
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frank. However, I could not replicate your answer on my side. It throws me various errors. Especially after the line of melt function as Error in patterns("2020$") : could not find function "patterns"
In addition: Warning message:
In melt(wdt, measure.vars = patterns("2020$"), variable.name = "date",  :
  The melt generic in data.table has been passed a data.frame and will attempt to redirect to the relevant reshape2 method; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. To continue using melt methods from reshape2 while ...

Comment: I realised that I have to convert my dataset into a data.table class in order to be able to use data.table::melt. This is not comfortable at all for me :( Still looking tidyr or reshape asnwer. Thanks for your effort by the way.

Comment: @ozturkib update with `tidyr` solution. The logic is the same...